# Can not import on impex for the job i created on code (hybris)

Tags: dynamic, sap-commerce-cloud

I followed that tutorial https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/everything-about-cronjobs-in-hybris-part-2/

but instead of string, i used customerlist parameter. like that:

```
    <attribute qualifier="customers" type="CustomersList">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" initial="false" optional="true" partof="true"/>
                <persistence type="jalo"/>//i changed this to  dynamic, because jalo gives error
            </attribute>
```

which i defined in

```
 <collectiontype code="CustomersList" elementtype="Customer" autocreate="true" generate="true" type="list"/>
```

at the bottom of tutorial, it says import those

```
INSERT_UPDATE ServicelayerJob   ;code[unique=true]  ;springId


INSERT_UPDATE HelloWorldCronJob ;code[unique=true]  ;job(code)      ;firstName
                                ;helloWorldCronJob  ;helloWorldJob  ;Mouad
```

i imported first and it was succesful.

but for second , i should change because i dont have that firstname area anymore. i changed it to customerlist so i should use another thing. also i tried to make it empty but errors are always same:

> ,,,,line 2: cannot create UsersFindCronJob with values
>   ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: , data:
>   {code=usersFindCronJob, job=usersFindJob(8796094628340)} ] due to
>   cannot find spring bean [UsersFindCronJob_customersAttributeHandler]
>   configured for dynamic attribute [UsersFindCronJob.customers] from
>   extension [trainingcore], line 3: cannot create UsersFindCronJob with
>   values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: , data:
>   {code=usersFindCronJob, job=usersFindJob(8796094628340)} ] due to
>   cannot find spring bean [UsersFindCronJob_customersAttributeHandler]
>   configured for dynamic attribute [UsersFindCronJob.customers] from
>   extension [trainingcore];usersFindCronJob;usersFindJob;Zohan

an example import that gave error:

```
INSERT_UPDATE UsersFindCronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);customers
;usersFindCronJob;usersFindJob;testcustomerbutthisisnotcustomerthisisstring
```

what should i do?

Comment: can you please provide more insight about what the cronjob you are creating should be doing, and why does the cronjob need to have a list of customers ?

Comment: when i go to backoffice, i could search with string and the job was retrieveing customer with that name. as in the tutorial. But now, i want to select customers on backoffice (i did this as single, when i make it customer instead of string , i could set customer on backoffice and job was retrieving it). now i have to make as list or collection. i dont want relation. collection is easier and i dont need relation

Comment: As a side note you should prefer the official tutorials from hybris which are up to date : https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8bc9823d86691014b5ced61a888b907a.html. The linked one is outdated and does not reflect the latest good practice.

Comment: Also the error is quite clear : cannot find spring bean [UsersFindCronJob_customersAttributeHandler] configured for dynamic attribute [UsersFindCronJob.customers... Somewhere you have defined `<persistence type="dynamic" attributeHandler="..." />` in items.xml for the customers attribute but the bean is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If persistence type is dynamic:

```
<persistence type="dynamic"/>
```

Then you need to create a Spring bean which should be responsible for computing the dynamic value based on other persistent attributes

An example of dynamic attribute could be the full name of a Customer, which 
can be computed by concatenating like this: **firstname** + **lastname** Where **firstname** and **lastname** are two attributes stored in the Database(persistence type="property")

If you want your attribute to be stored in the Database(and I believe that this is indicated) then you should set the persistence type to ***property*** instead of dynamic:

```
<persistence type="property"/>
```

Comment: i also tried that. despite intelj gives error `collections only defined jalo or dynamic ` but still same. i also put `optional="true"` and removed `partof` error is `due to cannot find spring bean [UsersFindCronJob_customersAttributeHandler] configured for dynamic attribute [UsersFindCronJob.customers] from extension [trainingcore], line 3: cannot create UsersFindCronJob with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {code=usersFindCronJob, customer=Zohan, job=usersFindJob(8796094628340)} ] due to cannot find spring bean [UsersFindCronJob_customersAttributeHandler] `

Comment: when i set property, inteljgives error but antcleanall or hybrisserverbat not. But import impex still gives error. same error when i try to import to job.should i make ant updatesystem?

Comment: yes, you should perform a platform update every time after altering the ${extensionName}-items.xml. This way the DB table associated with the cronjob will be updated with the new field

Comment: You can do it from hac( localhost:9002/hac) -> Platform -> Update and make sure you check the **Update running system** before starting the update.

Comment: i made ant updatesystem but still it says dynamic despite i made property . `UsersFindCronJob with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {code=usersFindCronJob, customer=Zoha, job=usersFindJob(8796094628340)} ] due to cannot find spring bean [UsersFindCronJob_customersAttributeHandler] configured for dynamic attribute [UsersFindCronJob.customers] from extension [trainingcore], line 3: cannot create UsersFindCronJob with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {code=usersFindCronJo`
`

Comment: Can you perform initialization ? That should redo the whole Database Schema, and, most probably the dynamic attribute handler problem will disappear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170298/discussion-between-dj-frunza-and-user9708984).

Comment: after intiialize, as property , it worked. no need relation

Answer (score 2):

Collectiontypes are deprecated. Prefer relations.

```
<relations>
    <relation code="UsersFindCronJob2CustomerRelation" localized="false" >
        <sourceElement type="UsersFindCronJob" cardinality="many" qualifier="usersFindCronJob" />
        <targetElement type="Customer" cardinality="many" qualifier="customer" />
    </relation>
</relations>
```

You can then import a cronjob like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE UsersFindCronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);customer(uid)
;usersFindCronJob;usersFindJob;myCustomerUid1, myCustomerUid2, myCustomerUid3
```

Comment: collectiontype came from default hybris zip. i did not use it. I only added one line where there are other collections